# Return column's values that has values from another table

Tags: sql

I have below 2 sample tables:

```
Orders: 
+--------+----------+
| UserID | ProductID| 
+--------+----------+
|      1 |    1     | 
|      2 |    4     |
|      3 |    3     | 
|      4 |    3     | 
+--------+----------+

Products:
+----------+-------+
| ProductID| Price | 
+----------+-------+
|      1   | A     | 
|      2   | D     | 
|      3   | G     |
|      4   | J     |
+----------+-------+
```

I would like to return the `ProductID` of `Products` table that only has value (or has `UserID`) in the `Orders` table.

So the results would be, the below column:

```
+----------+
| ProductID| 
+----------+
|      1   |  
|      3   | 
|      4   |
+----------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT ProductID FROM Products WHERE ProductID IN (SELECT ProductID from Orders)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about just doing:

```
select distinct productId
from orders;
```

Presumably, the `productid` is correct in the table -- so you don't have to check if a match actually occurs.

Comment: i needed to match with the other table to display only the productid of Products table that exists in the Users table, thanks though, i got my answer above with Apomene

Comment: @mylahg . . . Something is wrong with your data model if you have `productId` in `orders` that are not valid product ids.